# $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{p}$ Hamiltonian approach

Tags: condensed-matter, schroedinger-equation, semiconductor-physics, hamiltonian

I am new to reading into the $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{p}$ approach.
Where for a periodic function $u_{\vec{k}}$, which satisfies the Schrodinger equation:
$$
H_\vec{k}u_{\vec{k}}=E_{\vec{k}}u_{\vec{k}}
$$
which for a system parabolic-like system the Hamiltonian can be written as:
$$
H_\vec{k}= H_0 +H_{\vec{k}'}=H_0 + \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}+ \frac{\hbar \vec{k} \cdot \vec{p}}{m}
$$

If I am particularly looking at a semiconductor system comprised of a single generic valence and conduction band that is non-degenerate and I want to find the dispersion $E_{\vec{k}}$.
The Hamiltonian reads as:
$$
H= \begin{pmatrix}
E_c & \frac{\hbar}{m_0}\vec{k}\cdot \vec{p}_{cv} \\
 \frac{\hbar}{m_0}\vec{k}\cdot \vec{p}_{vc}  & E_v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From this expression how would I obtain $E_\vec{k}$, would it be simply the sum of the matrix above when diagonalised?

In addition, to the Hamiltonian above, if we wanted to include a magnetic field to the system where would it be included in this system? Would it be a component in the off-diagonal components?

I have reads that in the $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{p}$ approach we can include the magnetic field by rewriting $\vec{p}$ in terms of the magnetic vector potential